# Watson assistant entity created with pattern is not setting the matched value in context variable

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created a entity which has pattern to match 5 digits only, below is the pattern for that.

```
^([0-9]{5})*?$
```

[image]

But in the node when I am checking for slots and adding the value into a context variable, it is always taking the value name from entity not the value which user is providing.

Below is the image for the node.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For patterns you need to add the literal suffix.

So change your 5th slot "Check for" to:

```
@Customer_Id.literal
```

Without this your context variable only stores the value of the entity found. Which in your case is the same as the entity name.

Comment: what is the spel for a string with numbers and characters,size 5-10

Comment: @JohnRuby you can use https://regexr.com/ to build your regex patterns.